# Decrypt/Verify using PublicKey RSA OAEP_SHA1 on iPhone/iOS

Tags: ios, encryption, padding, verify, pkcs#1

I have a theoretical issue that I'm not able to understand.

Due to a special implementation about a signature/verify schema. I got a file ciphered by Private Key of a server. This Private Key is builded with OAEP SHA1 padding.

I haven't had problems for decipher this file in Android, Java and Windows using Bouncy Castle library.

I have googled but I didn't got any good solutions to decipher in iOS/iPhone plattaform, due to iOS hasn't implemented OAEPSHA1 protocol for decipher this file (only supports no padding or PKCS#1 padding. From: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/CryptoCompatibility/Listings/Read_Me_About_CryptoCompatibility_txt.html)

So I ask if someone know the theoretical concept about how to decipher using a PublicKey with OAEPSHA1 padding in iOS.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

So decrypt it in no-padding mode, and remove/verify OAEP padding by your code, it's not that hard.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry if it is a silly question, I'm starting programming in iOS security stuff and I'm a little confusing. I have no access to code, it is a theoretical question. I'm just try to learning how things work. So your recomendation it is that I have to decrypt my PublicKey PKCS OAEP with no padding mode? I also have read that OAEP schema it is not valid to verify data in PKCS#1 and I need to use PSS schema.  Am I wrong? But I can't figure how to convert from PublicKey OAEP to PublicKey PSS. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Under 'verify' I mean the correctness of OAEP padding. For sure, OAEP is used only for encryption, PSS - for signing. But both of them somehow pad data to be encrypted/signed, and then performs ordinary RSA operation. You can read details about OAEP/PSS in RFC 3447